# Moving from NHibernate to FluentNHibernate: assembly error (related to versions)?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Not sure where to start, but I had gotten the most recent version of NHibernate, successfully mapped the most simple of business objects, etc. When trying to move to FluentNHibernate and do the same thing, I got this error message on build:

> "System.IO.FileLoadException: Could
>   not load file or assembly 'NHibernate,
>   Version=2.1.0.4000, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does
>   not match the assembly reference."

Background: I'm new to Hibernate, NHibernate, and FluentNHibernate -- but not to .NET, C#, etc.

**Database**
I have a database table called Category:

(PK) CategoryID (type: int), unique, auto-incrementing
UserID (type: uniqueidentifier) -- given the value of the user Guid in ASP.NET database
Title (type: varchar(50) -- the title of the category

**Components involved:**

- I have a SessionProviderClass which creates the mapping to the database
- I have a Category class which has all the virtual methods for FluentNHibernate to override
- I have a CategoryMap : ClassMap class, which does the fluent mappings for the entity
- I have a CategoryRepository class that contains the method to add & save the category
- I have the TestCatAdd.aspx file which uses the CategoryRepository class.

Would be happy to post code for any of those, but I'm not sure that it's necessary, as I think the issue is that somewhere there's a version conflict between what FluentNHibernate references and the NHibernate I have installed from before.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: It appears the error has nothing to do with your code, and is more related to the project references. Have you tried removing the reference and re-adding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "Moving from NHibernate to FluentNHibernate".

FluentNHibernate is just an addon for NHibernate that provides a slightly different way to create the mappings.

The error message is clear: you are using a version of FluentNHibernate compiled for NHibernate 2.1.0, and you tried to use it with NHibernate 2.1.2, hence the version conflict.

Either download a version of Fluent that uses NH 2.1.2 or compile from source.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all,

The true answer was to remove and re-add the assemblies that came with FluentNHibernate (including the compatible version of NHibernate).

I also had to remember to add the correct references (for example, when using NHibernate, I had not added references to Castle.dll, etc.)

However, this uncovered more problems, which I'll post about in a separate thread.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem with that approach is that you are effectively using an outdated version of NHibernate that misses several fixes, just for the sake of using Fluent.

Comment: Fluent NHibernate works with the latest GA release of NHibernate, at the time of our 1.0 release that was 2.1.0 (I believe). The `master` branch is now running on 2.1.2GA, and that's what will be shipped with our imminent 1.1 release.